# Python can't decode PHP created JWT code

Tags: php, python, json, python-2.7, jwt

I am using python client and php server and JWT coded messages for communications. I have created a message in PHP but the Python JWT encoder says this is not a JSON object. For PHP JWT I use the Firebase JWT encoder (but the other JWT encoder the jwt_helper.php is the same, what I found on net). PHP version: PHP7, python: 2.7

Here is the code in php:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->result = 'OK';
$txt = json_encode($obj);

$secret_key = 'secret_key';

$encoded = Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($txt, $secret_key);
$decoded = Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($encoded, $secret_key, array('HS256'));

echo $decoded;
echo '<br />';
echo $encoded;
?>
```

The output is:
{"result":"OK"}
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.IntcInJlc3VsdFwiOlwiT0tcIn0i.dI4aO1UsXblWGCiLZbqQylRf8x6tgSWbeqYAw6rl5Sc

Now, I am trying the decode it in Python:

```
jwt.decode('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.IntcInJlc3VsdFwiOlwiT0tcIn0i.dI4aO1UsXblWGCiLZbqQylRf8x6tgSWbeqYAw6rl5Sc','secret_key')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 86, in decode
    raise DecodeError('Invalid payload string: must be a json object')
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid payload string: must be a json object
```

Could you help me? Maybe am I using wrong packages or wrong character coding? I tried exactly added the JSON output in PHP file, like $txt="{'result':'OK'}";, but the same error.
The other way works fine, if I create a JWT encoded string in Python, I can decode it in PHP.

Thanks and regards,
Kornel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token you produce in PHP is wrong.
Check your token on https://jwt.io/

It will show:

> Payload  data:
>
> "{\"result\":\"OK\"}"

The additional quotes are the problem.

Use the following code to produce your token instead:

```
$payload = array(
          "result" => "ok"
       );

$encoded  = Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($payload, $secret_key, "HS256");
```

You can add other values to the array as needed.